# copy std::string to 7-bit ASCII memory

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I've to copy a `std::string` to ASCII ... but with only **7bit** ASCII in memory. So this 8-Character string should fit into this 7-Byte/56Bit array.

```
std::string str = "12345678";
unsigned char ascii_destination[7];
```

I can grap every character from `str` and copy it with bit operations to its destinations but I was wondering if there is something more elegant to convert longer string to 7bit in memory? And I havn't found any built in functions for that... Thank you!

Comment: Outside of a `std::bitset` there aren't many easy way to manipulate bits besides working with data sized with full bytes directly and masking them to suit your needs.

Comment: What do you want to do with a string longer than 8 characters? It's impossible to compress it to 7 bytes. Maybe add an example?

Comment: What are you going to do with this 7bit ASCII string?  You certainly can't send it to any computer outside a museum (all communication these days is in terms of *octets* - 8 bits of data at a time.  It's quite common though for the range of values in the octet to be limited - for example to 7-bit ascii).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have only 56 bits, you can use a 64-bit integer as intermediate storage:

```
uin64_t temp = 0;

// Add 7 bits to temp, 8 times
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    temp = (temp << 7) | str[i];

// Remove 8 bits from temp, 7 times
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
{
    ascii_destination[i] = (uint8_t)(temp & 0xff);
    temp >>= 8;
}
```

(unless I understood completely wrong what you actually want)

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean [MIME encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) where `7bit` means that data is actually not encoded and is initially US ASCII. If it is not you can encode it in [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and specify that encoding.